# Calibration Curve v. Linear Dynamic Range

Tags: multiple-regression, linear, curve-fitting, calibration, chemometrics

We have a piece of analytical chemistry equipment (a mass spectrometer for those who care), that has the capacity to generate a "Response value" (Area under the curve) that correlates to the amount of a particular substance in the tested sample.  We analyze unknown samples and then validate with a wide range of external standard curves.

This is a common process in science but our process has run into some issues.  What has been recommended to us is to simply plot all the values, calculate the linear approximation, input the concentration of the unknown and solve for the unknown concentration... But the instrument is a bit more robust and has given us trouble (read: the instrument has a theoretically very wide linear dynamic range but we have values that fall all over the range)

The problem comes because the standard curves are produced via serial dilution and over a wide range (1ppm-1000ppm or similar 10^3+ ranges), the experimental values at the low end of the range are less than the discrepancy of the intercept.. causing all sorts of negative values.

I solve for the ideal curves by < 20% difference from expected across the ENTIRE curve.

So what I've done:

- Linear approximations
- 2nd and 3rd order approximations
- solving for ALL possible linear approximations that are minimum 5 pt curves and only interpolated..(I did this with an excel macro that I wrote)

Basically it's all getting messy because some of the values fall on ALL parts of the calibration range...

Any ideas of how you'd handle a highly variable data set (with 200+ distinct analyses per sample)?

Comment: Would there be any value in fitting to the lowest relative error rather than fitting to the lowest absolute error? That way a 10 percent error at the low end is fit equally well compared to a 10 percent error on the high end.